# php preg_replace pattern - replace text between commas

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string of words in an array, and I am using `preg_replace` to make each word into a link. Currently my code works, and each word is transformed into a link.

Here is my code:

```
$keywords = "shoes,hats,blue curtains,red curtains,tables,kitchen tables";

$template = '<a href="http://domain.com/%1$s">%1$s</a>';

$newkeys = preg_replace("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b([a-z]+)\b/is",    sprintf($template, "\\1"), $keywords);
```

Now, the only problem is that when I want 2 or 3 words to be a single link. For example, I have a keyword "blue curtains". The script would create a link for the word "blue" and "curtains" separately. I have the keywords separated by commas, and I would like the `preg_replace` to only replace the text between the commas.

I've tried playing around with the pattern, but I just can't figure out what the pattern would be.

Just to clarify, currently the output looks as follows:

```
  <a href="http://domain.com/shoes">shoes</a>,<a     href="http://domain.com/hats">hats</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/blue">blue</a>     <a href="http://domain.com/curtains">curtains</a>,<a     href="http://domain.com/red">red</a> <a href="http://domain.com/curtains">curtains</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/tables">tables</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/kitchen">kitchen</a> <a    href="http://domain.com/tables">tables</a>
```

While I want to achieve the following output:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/shoes">shoes</a>,<a      href="http://domain.com/hats">hats</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/blue      curtains">blue curtains</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/red curtains">red    curtains</a>,<a href="http://domain.com/tables">tables</a>,<a      href="http://domain.com/kitchen tables">kitchen tables</a>
```

Comment: put your expected output also in your code pls

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick reply. I  just edited my question added the current and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit change in `preg_replace` code and your job will done :-

```
$keywords = "shoes,hats,blue curtains,red curtains,tables,kitchen tables";

$template = '<a href="http://domain.com/%1$s">%1$s</a>';

$newkeys = preg_replace("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b([a-z ' ']+)\b/is",    sprintf($template, "\\1"), $keywords);

OR

$newkeys = preg_replace("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b([a-z' ']+)\b/is",    sprintf($template, "\\1"), $keywords);

echo $newkeys;
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/77tkyb

**Note:- I just added an white-space in your `preg_replace`. And you can easily get where it is. I hope i am clear.**

**Matching white-space along with words is missing there in `preg_replace` and i added that only.**

Comment: So mark it as your answer, so that other's can get advantage from this post. thanks:)))